# Многоточие после сокращающей точки

Tags: пунктуация, сокращения, многоточие

Можете сказать, съедается ли точка сокращения перед многоточием? Какой вариант правильный?

1. Он сказал, что в 1999 **г....**
2. Он сказал, что в 1999 **г...**

Comment: как мне тут недавно ответили:   "нетриангулируемые разнообразия в измерениях выше пятого порядка в практической ценности" - и как следовало из пояснения, это фраза значит, что 5-мерное пространство невозможно триангулировать. Вот я тут размышляю в связи с этим, а 5 точек подряд - никак?.. Может быть это и есть *нетриангулироемость*?

Comment: Если в тексте надо указать только год, то слово «год» не сокращается: *в 2019 году*. Источник: https://petr-panda.ru/kak-pysat-daty/

Comment: @Буратино
 здесь же все просто: надо четыре точки триангулировать в три...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь видны такие возможности оформления:
**в 1999 г...

в 1999 году...

в 1999-м...**

Четырех точек подряд никак быть не может!
У Лопатина:

> При сочетании в тексте **запятой и многоточия**... запятая опускается (поглощается многоточием...): — *А, например, как же цена, хотя, впрочем, это такой предмет... что о цене даже странно...* (Г.) — поглощена запятая перед придаточной частью...

Если запятая в середине предложения поглощается многоточием, то чем же точка в конце предложения хуже? Тоже поглощается.

В нашем предложении автор транслирует читателю чужую речь, мысль. В несобственно-прямой речи автор словно говорит или думает за персонажа.
Но человек не может закончить свое высказывание одинокой буквой "г" (на письме это возможно, в разговоре — нет).
Например: *Некто сказал: "Я лежал в больнице в 1999 г.".*
В этом случае возникает ощущение, что человек запнулся, не договорил слово "году", но тогда бы ставилось обычное многоточие.
Искусственный какой-то вариант, надуманный.

А вот второй и третий могут вообще обойтись без многоточий, так как в предложении отсутствует цитирование, которое при обрыве высказанных слов, собственно, и требует многоточия.
Пишем так: *Он сказал, что в 1999-м.*
Или так: *Он сказал, что в 1999 году.*
Или так: *Он сказал, что в девяносто девятом.*

P. S. Изменения в ответ внесены после комментария Г. Аванесовой. Спасибо!
Дополнение о трех точках: ["о сочетании вопросительного и восклицательного знаков и отточия"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%E2%84%96%20270133).

Comment: Римулик! В 1999 - низзя! Наращение падежное надобно! В 1999-м...

Comment: Ну да, ну да, я думала об этом. Для чего требуется наращение? Для того, чтобы определить падежное окончание порядкового числительного. Предполагаю, что заданное предложение — часть возможного диалога: *— Это было в двухтысячном году? — Нет. Он сказал, что в 1999.* В сочетании с предыдущим словом "году", мне кажется, позволительно обойтись и без наращения. P. S. Хотя, конечно, можно и добавить — следуя вашему замечанию. Ваше мнение всегда для меня ценно. P. P. S. Чтой-то Вы нечасто появляетесь. Жаль.

Comment: Ну, знак сокращения, в отличие от запятой, не поглощается ни запятой, ни тире, ни даже двоеточием, так что аргумент не очень. Наверно, таких ситуаций просто надо избегать. И в предложении многоточие относится не к цитированному материалу. Человек не знает, что сказать дальше, но обрыва речи нет. Разговорное употребление многоточия, не самое стандартное.

Comment: "Дык" я и сама написала, что в предложении отсутствует цитирование. А **максимальное количество** точечек, разрешенных правилами на сегодняшний день, — **три** (независимо от того, кто кого съедает, поглощает или еще что-то делает). Так что аргумент — очень. А дополнительные предложения — о четырех точках — академиками пока не утверждены. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%E2%84%96%20270133)

Comment: Ну вот этот аргумент уже получше. Тогда это непонятно: *А вот второй и третий могут вообще обойтись без многоточий, так как в предложении отсутствует цитирование*. Многоточие из-за того, что человек не знает, что сказать дальше (как бы ступор). Ещё есть вариант с пробелом после первой точки. Нестандартно, но красиво.

Comment: Да, наверно, красиво. Но! — многоточие по правилам  не отделяется пробелом от предыдущего слова (соответственно, и знака).

Comment: Отклонение от нормы во благо... Отклонения от нормы не обязательно ошибки. *А максимальное количество точечек, разрешенных правилами на сегодняшний день, — три* — это же не единый знак (четвероточие), а одна точка + многоточие (стык знаков, как запятая + тире), так что тоже не очень :)

Comment: Римулик, так  **— Это было в двухтысячном году? — Нет. Он сказал, что в 1999.** низзя. Наращение обязательно, никакой год из чужой реплики на него не влияет, но и ещё: недопустимо сочетать разное написание дат в одном тексте. **— Это было в 2000 году? — Нет. Он сказал, что в 99-м** или **— Это было в двухтысячном году? — Нет. Он сказал, что в девяносто девятом.**

Answer (score 0):

Если воспринимать задачу всерьёз и надолго, чего не хотелось бы...

**В 1999 г. ...**; **в MIM...**

После знака препинания поставить другой такой же, у которого не существует иного варианта формы, значит усложнить процесс чтения.